# How to iterate over NSArray quickly

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a method that iterates over an NSArray of NSDictionaries and changes values when an if statement is satisfied. However, for say 800 objects this can take 15-20 seconds.

I would like it to be much quicker and think maybe my logic could be improved. This is what I am doing:

```
// inside my method
for (int i = 0; i < [sortedItemsArray count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *tempInstForCopy = [sortedItemsArray objectAtIndex:i];
        tempInstObjectDictionary = [tempInstForCopy mutableCopy];
        tempInstForCopy = nil;
        // show InsFitButton
        if (([[tempInstObjectDictionary objectForKey:@"newIComp"] isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([[tempInstObjectDictionary objectForKey:@"newJCom"] isEqualToString:@"W"])) {
// make changes in here. continue with the loop.
```

Comment: You can try to use fast enumeration, but 15-20s to iterate over 800 objects clearly suggests that its what you do inside loop is a problem, not iterating itself

Comment: Are you going to change value in the array you are enumerating?

Comment: Also, it would be interesting to see what you are actually doing in the //make changes in here piece of your code. It might be possible to optimize things here as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try fast enumeration:

```
for (NSDictionary *tempInstForCopy in sortedItemsArray) {

}
```

Also, maybe you don't need to make copies of every dictionary for every entry, you can store then as mutable from the beggining.

Comment: Or just use mutable dictionaries in the first place, then you don't have to create temporary mutable copies all the time.

Comment: Yeah that's what I added

Comment: okay thanks.. going to look into changing over to NSMutableDictionary now.

Comment: fast enumeration will be faster due to less internal overheads, but I wonder if he wants to change tempInstForCopy in the fast-enumeration!!!

Comment: @AnoopVaidya i do change it inside the if statment.

Comment: I am not sure if you can do in this way. are you able to update?

Answer (score 1):

You can use fast enumeration for all the collection classes and its subclasses:

```
for (<objectType> objectName in <collectionObject>{
   ...
}
```

***Note***: You can't change/update the objectName in fast enumeration as it becomes constant.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most efficient approach

```
for (id object in array) {
    // do whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By iterating quickly I guess that you’re talking about the runtime of this loop right? For your example it would be faster if you wouldn’t have to create a copy of the dictionary every time. Try changing them into `NSMutableDictionary` types

When iterating through this array are there any cases where you can shorten the process? If you changed a value, do you have to continue the loop or can you `break;` (and maybe save the current index and continue when needed)?

I don’t know your exact problem, but oftentimes it’s possible to split up big arrays like this in smaller subarrays which you can target better.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the answers to make the loop itself faster, I agree that the loop is not your problem, but what you do inside the loop.

Before changing the items into mutable dictionary I would use a custom class.

On a first view there are two problems:

- You create a mutable copy for every item. Object creation is potentially slow.
- You have to insert the changed copy into the array again, don't you?

Both operations would be less expensive, if you have instances of a custom class (or of mutable dictionary). Without changing the type of the items, it would improve the runtime behavior, if you create the mutable copy (`tempInstObjectDictionary`) only inside the `if`, so it is only created when it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Speed optimizing is always "fun". Beware though the below tips might not help in your particular case and are designed for speed not readability. (Which is a big red flag).

In addition to the fast enumeration tips from Antonio MG and changing the dictionaries to Mutable earlier in the stack there are a few other steps you might look into:

If for instance you know that `[[tempInstObjectDictionary objectForKey:@"newIComp"] isEqualToString:@"T"]` registers TRUE *a lot* more often than `[[tempInstObjectDictionary objectForKey:@"newJCom"] isEqualToString:@"W"]` (or vice versa) you could save some cycles nesting the two ifs*, checking first at the rarest case:

```
if ([[tempInstObjectDictionary objectForKey:@"newJCom"] isEqualToString:@"W"]){
    if ([[tempInstObjectDictionary objectForKey:@"newIComp"] isEqualToString:@"T"]){
        // make changes in here. continue with the loop.
    }
}
```

Also, depending on your design and what you are trying to achieve, you might improver performance by adding the dictionaries you need to change to a new array, and alter them on another thread after you've finished your loop...

*Actually I'm not sure if you even need to nest them, switching the order might achieve the same thing(?) Any compiler-experts feel free to chime in...